# Exceptions with SSL Code

Tags: exception, ssl

I'm having a problem that I can't figure it out. I'm testing a SSL code that connects to a remote website, and everything works great on my computer. BTW, I imported the certificate from the website with:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore /java/path/to/cacerts -trustcacerts -alias “Cert Alias” -file website_certificate.cer
```

The problem appears when I upload and test the code on the server. I get the following exceptions:

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
>
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
>
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter:

I checked the date on the server and it is up to date, and the certificate expires on 2012.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check every certificate in the path. Either one of them has expired or the date isn't set correctly on the server.

Comment: None of the certificates have expired and the server date is set correctly.

Comment: Ok, then you're checking the wrong certificates. The one referenced by that exception is expired.

Comment: I don't think so. It works fine on my computer. The problem appears on the server.

Comment: Maybe the server is making a different connection and getting some other certificate chain containing an expired server. Feel free to examine sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.java for yourself if you have doubts.